# How can I use the same domain for separate App Engine projects (dev and prod)?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have two independent App Engine projects to serve my REST API, one for my development environment and the other for production. I have the custom domain `example.com` and want to serve the development API at `dev-api.example.com` and the production API at `api.example.com`.

I can add `dev-api.example.com` and `api.example.com` as custom domains in each project and get the same list of A and AAAA DNS records for each (the CNAME obviously differs).

My two questions are:

1. Can I safely add the CNAMEs for both projects (`dev-api` and `api`) to the same DNS records?
2. Will App Engine be able to point to the correct project just based on those domain prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

`dev-api.example.com` and `api.example.com` can be mapped to separate App Engine Projects.

You can add the same CNAMEs for both projects without any issues. GCP will be able able to route your requests to the correct App Engine Projects based on the Custom Domain config in your App Engine settings.